# three js simple project showing black screen

Tags: three.js

Started playing around with three.js, following these two tutorials:

http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2014/01/photo-spheres-with-threejs.html

and

http://threejs.org/docs/#Manual/Introduction/Creating_a_scene

and I've come up with this code so far:

```
var camera, scene, renderer;
var geometry, material, mesh;

init();

function init() {

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
  camera.position.z = 1000;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.SphereGeometry(100, 32, 32),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('photos.jpg')
    })
  );

  sphere.scale.x = -1;

  scene.add(sphere);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(400, 400);
  renderer.render(scene,camera);

  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}
```

really just trying to follow along the guides, and yet when I run this in my browser (Chrome) all I get is a black screen. No errors to speak of, except for this warning:

```
THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture has been deprecated. Use THREE.TextureLoader() instead.
```

Note that the photo I'm using is a photosphere photo I took with my phone (as it should be per the first guide I'm following).

The expected result is something like what the first guide is producing.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

**Edit**

corrected the warning by replacing

```
  var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.SphereGeometry(100, 32, 32),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('photos.jpg')
    })
  );
```

with

```
  var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
  var texture = loader.load('photos.jpg');
  var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.SphereGeometry(100, 32, 32),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      map: texture
    })
  );
```

still a black screen

Comment: have you added the animate function for rendering

Comment: negative, but why would i need to animate to just see the sphere?

Comment: the texture may not get loaded on the first call of the function ,also the scene is not rendered when the Image is loaded

Answer (score 0):

Cross origin issues. had to run the file from a server. go figure.

Answer (score -1):

```
sphere.material.side = THREE.BackSide;
```

Comment: nope, that does not work. in fact, by adding that it causes the black screen again unless i used `THREE.DoubleSide`; but either way the solution i ended up finding is the right one